# Android change Launcher Icon

Tags: android, android-launcher, launcher-icon

I added a new launcher icon to my application by following the path below.

```
Res> new > Immage Asset
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

and AndroidManifest.xml look like that :

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I want to create a circle logo, but my phone has a square logo, but a circle on the emulator.What could this be caused by? (also the logo of all the apps on my phone is square)

Comment: I think the change is not reflected in your mipmap file, you can check the same. And can you share the screenshot for your mipmap directory under res?

Comment: The circle icon is not related to any app but to launcher or phone company..

Comment: Also since you are using the android studio tool, it depends on the os version which icon is displayed, you could try using [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html) choosing a circle type and just importing those files

Comment: How do I add the downloaded file to the project?

Comment: @javdromero  I added the file into drawable and change the Manifestfile like that `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"         android:label="@string/app_name"         android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` . Is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You app icon, is basically a background with a mask on top. Different Android manufacturers use different masks. Some use a square image, and some use rounded images. Hence, the result is different for many devices. Looks like your device happens to use a square mask.

A lot of devices have an option to change this in the general settings of your phone.
E.g. for One Plus, you can find it under "Customisation | System Icons"

Comment: I use @javdromero and add file in drawable after that I change the manifest like that  `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` . And the icon is circler now. is that use correct ?

Comment: It's ok, now you only provide one type of icon so it will be that one in every device, before you created alternatives based on the api version. Is it according to android recommendations? No, but it's just that a recommendation, not a rule. at least for now